# blank page when trying to access Magento collection

Tags: magento, magento-1.13

I have a custom block for my customer/dashboard page, and while everything works, I cannot use the following:

```
 public function getOrders(){

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
            ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
        ;


        return $collection;
    }
```

I get a blank page if I access this method. I want to load orders and display them  on my dashboard. I took this query from the sales order Mage module.

Am I able to access resources from different modules?

Edit:

I limited it to return one order, but no dice.

```
   $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
            ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
            ->setPageSize(1)
            ->setCurPage(1);
```

Comment: How many orders are there in your Magento installation? If you have a lot of orders that may also create problem. Or try to enable the error messages and debug the white screen issue.

Comment: Perhaps that the problem. What if I limit the amount of orders returned

Answer (score 0):

Above code is working there is no problem in code,

Now you need to check is you are getting customer id from

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
```

If you are getting customer id then error is in other code of you file or another file. It may have syntax error.

Comment: do I need to add the sales/order_collection resource to the module config I'm using?

Comment: no need to add it. Use this Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();  then check it.